# multiple addError() behaviour in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, exception, adderror

We have a trigger on the `Account` and `Contact` objects. The job of these triggers is to prevent the deletion of Account and Contact objects depending on the criteria.

`Account` should be deleted if no contact is associated with it, else an error should be displayed by using `addError('custom error message').`

```
trigger Account_BD on Account (before delete) {
    //Get all contacts associatd with the Accounts and fill it in map
    for (Id accountId : trigger.oldMap.keyset()) {
        if (//check if contact exists) {
            trigger.oldMap.get(accountId).addError('Error while deleting account');
        }
        else {
            contacts.add(contact); //added contact from the contact map
        }
    }
    delete contacts;
}
```

`Contact` should be deleted if no Project Roles are associated with it, else an error should be displayed by using `addError('custom error message')`.

```
trigger Contact_BD on Contact  (before delete) {
    //get all Project Roles in map
    for (Contact contactRecord : (List<Contact>)trigger.oldMap.values()) {
        if (//check if project role is associated with contact) {
            contactRecord.addError('Error while deleting contact');
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is when the trigger on Account is fired the following error is received:
[image]

You'll notice that it is not displaying the custom error message but a generic Salesforce one.

If I remove the `addError()` from the Contact trigger the `addError()` on Account works fine.

I see that [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) has answered a similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237042/adderror-on-an-object-in-a-trigger-is-only-displaying-one-of-the-errors-in-objec). I just want to confirm that we can't use multiple addError() calls in one transaction?

**If that is the case would it be possible to substitute the `addError()` with a `throw new Exception()`**

Comment: So, you say that you want to only allow deleting the account if no contacts are on the account, but then you go about deleting contacts on the accounts? Can you please verify the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: P.S. you can have more than one addError per transaction, but you can only have one at the top-level record, and one per field. However, your code, as written, throws an exception, so only the first error can be returned in its current state. You must use a partial update and then bubble up any errors to the parent updates.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes that is the behaviour we are looking for. There is more than one criteria involved but for the sake of this post, I have not included them as it would be too complex.

What do you mean by "You must use a partial update and then bubble up any errors to the parent updates" I'm afraid I'm not following.

Comment: @sfdcfox do you think it makes sense to replace the addError with throw new Exception?

Comment: No. In fact, I specifically recommend [not doing this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/303270/2984). You can, and should, generally use partial updates, as I explain in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/187929/2984). It requires a bit more code than simply throwing an exception, but allows partial updates to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to switch from `addError` to `throw`. If you do so, you will make all bulk operations all-or-none, disabling partially successful saves. Maybe you will decide that is a worthy tradeoff, but it is a brittle architecture and I would fight against it if someone suggested it in any org I've worked on.

Comment: In that case, what do you recommend I should do?

Comment: You haven't really described your user flow at all so it's hard to say.